# Ordering a character matrix by numerical column

Tags: r, matrix, character

I'm working with a matrix read in from a csv that contains both numbers and characters. This is a smaller matrix, but basically what I'm working with:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]         [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]
V2  "A"  "1"  "Sample X1"  "34712" "39390" "38858" "38574" "38660" 
V3  "A"  "2"  "Sample X2"  "35333" "39940" "40533" "39936" "40669" 
V4  "A"  "3"  "Sample X3"  "33612" "39601" "38658" "39220" "39465" 
V5  "A"  "4"  "Sample X4"  "34309" "39200" "38597" "39820" "40081" 
V6  "A"  "5"  "Sample X5"  "33637" "39404" "40497" "39388" "40033" 
V7  "A"  "6"  "Sample X6"  "35314" "39522" "40345" "38624" "40306" 
V8  "A"  "7"  "Sample X7"  "35548" "39000" "41408" "38310" "39849" 
V9  "A"  "8"  "Sample X8"  "33972" "39930" "39777" "39582" "39570" 
V10 "A"  "9"  "Sample X9"  "34808" "39857" "39252" "39248" "38465" 
V11 "A"  "10" "Sample X10" "34316" "39798" "39776" "39516" "38812" 
V12 "A"  "11" "Sample X11" "34476" "38581" "39672" "38997" "38794" 
V13 "A"  "12" "Sample X12" "36246" "38809" "37872" "38100" "36925" 
V14 "B"  "1"  "Sample X13" "33642" "40201" "40202" "39320" "40426" 
V15 "B"  "2"  "Sample X14" "33381" "40624" "40349" "41350" "40490" 
V16 "B"  "3"  "Sample X15" "34465" "42096" "41194" "40613" "40416" 
V17 "B"  "4"  "Sample X16" "33957" "41905" "42273" "40710" "40681" 
V18 "B"  "5"  "Sample X17" "33877" "42040" "42226" "40788" "41261" 
V19 "B"  "6"  "Sample X18" "33970" "41860" "41149" "41093" "40877" 
V20 "B"  "7"  "Sample X19" "34745" "42040" "40186" "40862" "41044" 
V21 "B"  "8"  "Sample X20" "34140" "41274" "39880" "40356" "40496" 
V22 "B"  "9"  "Sample X21" "33929" "40652" "41410" "40760" "40718" 
V23 "B"  "10" "Sample X22" "33684" "39220" "40478" "41500" "40094"
V24 "B"  "11" "Sample X23" "33141" "41446" "41121" "40726" "41020"
V25 "B"  "12" "Sample X24" "33405" "38481" "37716" "38562" "38218" 
V26 "C"  "1"  "Sample X25" "71560" "86402" "85614" "84273" "83264" 
V27 "C"  "2"  "Sample X26" "72144" "86266" "88082" "87672" "87356" 
V28 "C"  "3"  "Sample X27" "71946" "90201" "89156" "88386" "88006" 
V29 "C"  "4"  "Sample X28" "71758" "89108" "88225" "86006" "88654" 
V30 "C"  "5"  "Sample X29" "71144" "86558" "88614" "87028" "88809" 
V31 "C"  "6"  "Sample X30" "70504" "89230" "88869" "86653" "86356" 
V32 "C"  "7"  "Sample X31" "67874" "88405" "84878" "84914" "85425" 
V33 "C"  "8"  "Sample X32" "70273" "87865" "87529" "87945" "86172"
```

I would like sort the matrix by the second column without headers so it goes:

```
A 1 . . .
B 1
C 1
A 2
B 2
C 2
A 3
. 
.
.
A 12
B 12
C 12 . . .
```

I've looked around and found that you can use order:

```
data <- data[order(data[,2],]
```

but it comes out like this:

```
A 1 . . .
B 1
c 1
A 10
B 10
C 10
A 11
B 11
C 11
A 12
B 12
C 12
A 2
B 2
C 2
.
.
.
A 9
B 9
C 9 . . .
```

Is it because this matrix is a character matrix? How do I go about making only the second column numerical so I can sort it based off that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your data in a matrix is a bad idea when you want to have a mix of classes (e.g. numeric and character) across columns. Instead, you should be using a dataframe.

Ideally, read the data into a dataframe with `read.csv` or `read.table`. Otherwise, coerce your matrix to a dataframe with `as.data.frame`.

Given matrix `m` (in your case `data`):

```
d <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d[, 3] <- as.numeric(d[, 3]) # coerce the relevant column to numeric
d[order(d[, 3]), ]
```

Note that you *could* order the matrix as desired with `m[order(as.numeric(m[, 3])), ]`, but the resulting columns will still all be `character`.

NB: The explanation for the sorting behaviour that you witnessed is that for a character vector, anything beginning with a `1` (e.g. `10`) comes before `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about data.frame, I was confused how to have data of multiple classes. Is there anyway to change the way it is sorted? To be 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 10, 11, 12? Or is the best way just to cut those rows out and put them at the end?

Comment: @IlyaLederman not sure what you mean. The code I provided (d <- as.data.frame(data); d[order(d[, 3]), ]`), or `data[order(as.numeric(data[, 3])), ]`, should both order it as you wanted.

Comment: I am still getting the order as 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,9,7,8,9. I did lapply(data, class) and it says everything is a factor. I don't really understand what a factor is. I read in csv like 
data<-t(read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE, skip=5))[-1,]
 then do
data <- as.data.frame(data)

Comment: For factor data you need to use `d <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); d[order(d[, 3]), ])` or `data[order(as.numeric(as.character(data[, 3]))), ]`.

Comment: I was still getting it ordered as characters using as.data.frame, but doing the as.numeric and as.character made it work. Thank you!

Comment: @IlyaLederman - Apologies, I skipped the step of coercing that column to numeric. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Would you also happen to know how to convert all the numbers in my matrix to numeric? I try to do data[,5:len] <- as.numeric(data[,5:len]) where len is the number of columns, but I get "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Comment: @IlyaLederman `data[, -(1:4)] <- lapply(data[, -(1:4)], as.numeric)` - will work for a data.frame or list, but not for a matrix, which requires that all columns are the same type.